# How to save loop data in multiple JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have some variables in a loop, that are needed to be saved in a JSON. But need to make sure the next time loop iterates, the previously created JSON doesn't overwrite.

```
try {
  ayats.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.toLowerCase().includes(request.params.find.toLowerCase())===true)
    {
      counting++;
      element=JSON.parse(element);
      Surah_Name = element.SuratName;
      Ayat_No = element.AyatNo;
      x = "In Surah "+ element.SuratName+", Ayat Number: "+element.AyatNo+", Quran says: "+ element.Translation;

      // Here some logic to save Surah_Name, Ayat_No and x in JSON
    }
  }
}
```

Required output is like this:

```
{
 "data1":{"Surah_Name": Surah_Name,"Ayat_No": Ayat_No, "x":x},
 "data2":{"Surah_Name": Surah_Name,"Ayat_No": Ayat_No, "x":x},
 "data3":{"Surah_Name": Surah_Name,"Ayat_No": Ayat_No, "x":x},
}
```

Comment: Not really clear with the question. Are we talking about a JSON object or a JSON file here?

Comment: you should print an array of JSON objects not JSON of JSON

Comment: Use for loop instead

Comment: Why would you use an object and keys like `data1`, `data2`...etc rather than putting them in an array and using `data[1]`, `data[2]`?

Comment: Instead of setting data back in element, You should create another variable before the loop, and add the data in it in every iteration

Comment: What is `request.params`?

Comment: If you really want to edit the same variable and don't want to create the new variable, use .map or .filter method for looping instead of foreach,

Comment: @AmitDas JSON object

Comment: @zer00ne I have taken a snippet of code. Never mind what is that, because full code is lengthy. I want to save variables 'Surah_Name', "Ayat_No' and 'x' in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
function getData(ayats){

const parentObj={};
let counting=0;
  ayats.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.toLowerCase().includes(request.params.find.toLowerCase())===true)
    {
      counting++;
      element=JSON.parse(element);
      Surah_Name = element.SuratName;
      Ayat_No = element.AyatNo;
      x = "In Surah "+ element.SuratName+", Ayat Number: "+element.AyatNo+", Quran says: "+ element.Translation;
      const tempObj={
        Surah_Name,
        Ayat_No,
        x
      }
      parentObj[`data${counting}`]=tempObj
      // Here some logic to achieve the required output
    }
  })
  return parentObj;
}

console.log(getData(ayats))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = {};
var counting = 0;

ayats.forEach(function (element) {
  if (!element.toLowerCase().includes(request.params.find.toLowerCase())) return; //return means skip(continue)
  element = JSON.parse(element);
  Surah_Name = element.SuratName;
  Ayat_No = element.AyatNo;

  // Here some logic to achieve the required output
  result[`data${++counting}`] = {
    Surah_Name: Surah_Name,
    Ayat_No: Ayat_No,
    x: `"In Surah: ${Surah_Name} Ayat Number: ${Ayat_No} Quran says: ${element.Translation}`
  };
})

console.log(result)
```